# Is Thanos actually good?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

I know it seems crazy, but anyway I'll ask. In the middle of Infinity war, Thanos beats Guardians and teleports with Gamora. After that, they had a conversation:

> ***Gamora:*** I was a child when you took me.
>
> ***Thanos:*** I saved you.
>
> ***Gamora:*** No, no, we were happy on my home planet.
>
> ***Thanos:*** Going to bed hungry, scrounging for scraps? Your planet was on
>   the brink of collapse. I was the one who stopped that. You know what's
>   happened since then? The children born have known nothing but full
>   bellies and clear skies. It's a paradise.

So, Thanos spends his time, trying to make world better?

Comment: It's worth remembering that Gamora is the last of her species according to *Guardians of the Galaxy 1*, so the jury is still out on whether Thanos was telling the truth about her planet or not.

Comment: Most well-written villains *think* they are good. Doesn't make it true.

Comment: @MeatTrademark He convinced me :)

Comment: What does "good" mean? You need to define that. The avengers certainly didn't think Thanos was, but he does. Good and bad are relative in many scenarios.

Comment: Obligatory r/thanosdidnothingwrong

Comment: @F1Krazy I oppose that with the dialogue from Avengers:endgame: what [Nebula](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Nebula) says: *"My father is blablaaa....(not interested); A lier, its not one of them"*. something like that. That means he does not lie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer with no citations...

Yes *[but no]*.
Thanos **thinks** he is doing 'a good thing'.
He thinks he is trying to save the Universe from over-population.

He is simply going about it the wrong way.

His thought process<sup>[1]</sup>...

> If you halve the population, you have half the people consuming all the resources....

ermm... **wrong**

If you suddenly halve the population you get

- panic
- not enough people in the right jobs to get the food to the people
- assuming those survivors, who may have randomly lost spouses/children, survive not only that heartbreak and the collapse of civilisation as they know it, and start to reproduce as though nothing happened - or even at intense rate because of perceived under-population - you will be back at square one inside a century.

## #FAIL

We, of course, don't know yet how his plan will backfire - but unless they're going to permanently wipe out half the Marvel Cinematic Universe [<sup><sub>no spoilers</sub></sup>], then backfire it must.

<sup>[1] which is, of course, the thought process of every 'eebil megalomaniac', real or imaginary, since time began</sup>

Comment: Well, he is right from his point of view. He has seen his own planet destroyed and no one listened to him calling him a mad man and he probably would have seen many more such planets